How does SkadNetwork 4.0 match a user's click on an ad with App Install?
I have a question that I can't find the answer to even in the Apple documentation.
How does SKAdNetwork 4.0 match ad clicks with application installation?
From what I read in the documentation, this is what an example ad link looks like
<a href="https://apps.apple.com/app/id{itunes_item_id}" 
attributionDestination="https://example.com" 
attributionSourceNonce="t8naKxXHTzuTJhNfljADPQ">
</a>

Is this data (e.g. attributionSourceNonce) saved somehow on the device and later sent together with the application installation?
I've read the documentation, blog entries from other companies and, as a last resort, I've used the chat GPT, but I can't find a specific answer anywhere.
